# how to take svndump of a proejct from a very large repo

Tags: svn, svnadmin, svndump

We have repository with project specific branches and tags.Just a snapshot of my repo  here :

1. Project Code
       =====>>branches
   ---- R1
   ---- R2
   ---- R3

   ```
     =====>> tags
   ```

--- R1_tag
--- R2_tag

Project Database
=======>> Branches
---- R1
---- R2
---- R3

```
          ======>>tags
```

--- R1_tag
--- R2_tag

Now I want to take dump of a branch in project Code only and then load this dump to other repo on same server.
I tried following but that *results in empty revisions* being loaded in other repo .

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo | svndumpfilter include /proj > dump-file
svnadmin create /new/proj/repo
svnadmin load --ignore-uuid /new/proj/repo < dump-file
```

and I can't run above commands sequentially as Repo is too large and creating dump might take 10 hours atleast.Further more , ignoring UUID is for removing linking to present repository or any other reasons for it? 
Please help with specific commands .

Answer (score 0):

`svndumpfilter` has an option to drop empty revisions, `--drop-empty-revs`.

If you don't have a specific reason to use `--ignore-uuid`, then try without it. If it works, you don't need it.

You can streamline the dump - filter - load operations without an intermediary dump file, like this:

```
svnadmin create /new/proj/repo
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo | svndumpfilter include /proj --drop-empty-revs | svnadmin load /new/proj/repo
```

Comment: I did try this but "svnadmin dump /path/to/repo " starts from rev#1 but my required project lies after rev#50,000 .So is it normal or I am doing something wrong here .And I tried "--drop -empty revs" too but on loading still revision set  were empty and no action was performed for tht revision

Comment: I tested this and it correctly excluded the empty revisions. There is another flag, `--drop-all-empty-revs` but I'm not sure of the difference. I cannot test again before the evening, in the meantime you can give that a try.